# How to select muliple choices from another model?

Tags: django

**Lab_Group Model**

```
class Lab_Group(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,)
```

**Lab Model**

```
class Lab(models.Model):
    laboratory = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Lab_Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Lab Request Model**

```
class LabRequest(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lab_test = models.ManyToManyField(Lab)
```

As you see I have these models each one relates the other one. In the **LabRequest** model I want to select some list from **Lab** model as **multiple choice** .

I have a template where I want to select a **lab_test** from **Lab** model as checkboxes. Please guide me on how do I do that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use django widgets, link:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple

```
lab_test = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=Lab.objects.all()
    )
```

Comment: If I try to use this way it says: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: If I try to use this way also it fine but it displays as dropdown list but I want as checkboxes:  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LabRequestModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['lab_test'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Lab.objects.all())

Comment: check for some packages like django-select2  https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html

Comment: It's displaying like big long dropdown list, but is it possible as checkboxes?